# Spring JPA Repository returns list of identical objects

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring JPA Repository which behaves in a strange way. To be precise, it returns a list of objects which all appear to be identical, although the underlying database query seems to be returning the correct information.

The entity class is below. It corresponds to a View in MySQL.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Cacheable(false)
@Table(name="view_assignment_selector")
public class AssignmentSelectorView {

    @EmbeddedId private ID id;
    private int areaId;
    private String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) private Preference preference;
    private int assigned;
    private int required;
    private boolean selected;


    @Embeddable @Getter
    public static class ID implements Serializable {
        private Integer volunteerId;
        private Integer sessionId;
    }

}
```

Here is the Repository:

```
public interface AssignmentSelectorViewRepository extends JpaRepository<AssignmentSelectorView, AssignmentSelectorView.ID> {
    List<AssignmentSelectorView> findByIdVolunteerIdAndIdSessionId(int volunteerId, int sessionId);
}
```

Here is the generated query as logged by MySQL:

```
SELECT AREAID, ASSIGNED, NAME, PREFERENCE, REQUIRED, SELECTED, SESSIONID, VOLUNTEERID FROM view_assignment_selector WHERE ((VOLUNTEERID = 820) AND (SESSIONID = 32))
```

When I try the query in MySQL directly, the result is correct. But the list of `AssignmentSelectorView` objects is the correct size, but all entries are identical to the first.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Lesson learned - by extra careful with Ids.
It's quite tricky to write @Entity classes for Views because Views don't really have Primary Keys, but the @Entity class still needs an Id.

My original Id was wrong in that the 2 columns were not unique. I needed a 3rd column. The correct Id is:

```
@Embeddable @Getter
public static class ID implements Serializable {
    private Integer volunteerId;
    private Integer sessionId;
    private Integer areaId;
}
```

Now it works.

Comment: Thanks for this update, i was going crazy :D